# Testing absolute url for models in django

Tags: python, django, testing, django-models

in my model for userprofile.

```
 def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('user_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

in my test.py

```
  def test_get_absolute_url(self):
    user = UserProfile.objects.get(id=1)
    self.assertEqual(user.get_absolute_url(), '/writecloud/user/1')
```

well i wanna know if what i wrote in assertEqual() is correct to test this. im not sure how to use kwargs

Comment: You could just do `return reverse('user_detail', pk=self.pk)`.

Comment: after the user=UserProfile.objects line?

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. The second line in the first block of code.